# \emph not working well in amsthm's "plain" style using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, amsthm, italic

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
  This is an \emph{example lemma}.
\end{lemma}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

I expect "This is an" to be italicized as per the "plain" theorem style, and "example lemma" to be made upright by the `\emph` command.  However, this does not happen and "example lemma" stays italicized as well.

Note that this does not happen using plain LaTeX, but it happens with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved by an update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the redefinition of `\em` performed by `fontspec`, which doesn't take into account the context, but only nesting of `\em` inside `\em`.

The following workaround should work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:cpn {th@plain} { \int_zero:N \l__fontspec_em_int \em }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
  This is an \emph{example lemma}.
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

The default for `\th@plain` is to expand to `\itshape`; making it expand to `\em` brings nesting in sync.

It's related to this [issue report to `fontspec](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/246#issuecomment-230644777).

In case you prefer that a statement appearing in an `\em` context is typeset upright, remove the `\int_zero:N \l__fontspec_em_int` part from the redefinition of `\th@plain`.

[image]

Comment: Imho one could use `\renewcommand{\th@plain}{\int_zero:N \l__fontspec_em_int\em}` if one want to avoid that an external \em interferes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer MIght be, but it's possibly not the what one wants in that case.

Comment: The default definition of lemma is to use \itshape -- which is independant from external font settings, so I would at first try to mimic this.

Comment: BTW with the next version of fontspec (for TL2017) this should be improved/fixed.